# Some bookmarklets don't execute on iOS: How to debug?

Tags: javascript, ios, bookmarklet

**Update 2:** Apparently, bookmarklets as long as 2410 characters *do* work fully after all, which I tested with a script of the form `javascript: var a=0; a++; a++; ... window.alert(a);`. At 9424 characters, Chrome sync for the bookmarklet failed, but by copy/pasting the bookmark from an Email, I was still able to execute it. It remains unclear, why some scripts work when served as a script tag (see Update 1), but fail when executed from a `javscript:` URL directly.

**Update 1:** It looks like the same bookmarklet will work, by generating a `<script/>` tag pointing to the script hosted on dropbox. <strike>This only really leaves as explanation, that the browser engine on iOS has a hardcoded limit of less than 1024 characters for `javascript:` URLs.</strike>

## Original Post

I am trying to figure out why some bookmarklets do nothing – not even trigger an error – on iOS, having no access to a Mac OS device.

For reference, consider the following two bookmarklets (formatted source below):

```
// DebugSimple.js
javascript:/* DebugSimple.js - 10:02:50 2019-12-23 */(function(){ document.body.innerHTML='';document.body.style.all='initial';function putString(string){document.body.innerText+=string;}const oldConsoleLog=console.log;console.log=function(...args){putString('(log) '+args.map(e=>e.toString()).join(' '));return oldConsoleLog(...args);};window.addEventListener('error',event=>{var msg='\n(err) ';msg+=!event ?'!!event = '+event :!event.error ?'!!event.error = '+event.error :!event.error.stack ?'!!event.error.stack = '+event.error.stack : event.error.stack;if(event&&event.error)for(const key in event.error){msg+='\nevent.error.'+key+'='+event.error[key];}putString(msg);});console.log("Log test.");setTimeout(backtraceTest,10);function backtraceTest(){backtraceTest2();}function backtraceTest2(){noSuchFunctionShouldExist();}})();undefined;

// DebugOverlay.js
javascript:/* DebugOverlay.js - 10:07:25 2019-12-23 */(function(){ const highestZIndex=Math.max(...Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).map(e=>window.getComputedStyle(e).zIndex).map(parseInt).filter(e=>!isNaN(e)));console.log(highestZIndex);function append(parent,html,callback=undefined){var e=document.createElement('DIV');parent.appendChild(e);e.outerHTML=html;e=parent.lastElementChild;if(callback)callback(e);return e;}const ifr=document.createElement('IFRAME');document.body.prepend(ifr);ifr.id='debugOverlay.js';ifr.style.all='initial';ifr.style.zIndex=highestZIndex+1;ifr.style.position='fixed';ifr.style.left='5%';ifr.style.right='5%';ifr.style.width='90%';ifr.style.height='90%';ifr.style.opacity='90%';ifr.style.backgroundColor='#ddd';ifr.style.border='1pt solid #888';ifr.contentDocument;ifr.contentDocument.open();ifr.contentDocument.close();const header=append(ifr.contentDocument.body,"<DIV id='header'/>",e=>{e.style.position='static';});const closeButton=append(header,"<A href='#' id='closeButton'>[CLOSE]</A>",e=>{e.addEventListener('click',()=>ifr.parentElement.removeChild(ifr));});const clearButton=append(header,"<A href='#' id='clearButton'>[CLEAR]</A>",e=>{e.addEventListener('click',()=>{output.innerHTML='';});});const output=append(ifr.contentDocument.body,"<DIV id='outputPane'/>",e=>{e.style.fontFamily='Sans';});append(ifr.contentDocument.body,"<DIV id='overScroll' style='height:30vh'/>");var fontSizeScale=0.8;function setOutputFontSize(scale){output.style.fontSize=(fontSizeScale*100)+'%';}setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale);const fontSizePlus=append(header,"<A href='#' id='fontSizePlus'>[LGR]</A>",e=>{e.addEventListener('click',()=>{setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale*=1.2);});});const fontSizeMinus=append(header,"<A href='#' id='fontSizePlus'>[SML]</A>",e=>{e.addEventListener('click',()=>{setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale/=1.2);});});const toggleLog=append(header,"<A href='#' id='toggleLog'>[log(on)]</a>",e=>{var logVisibility=true;e.addEventListener('click',()=>{setLogVisibility(logVisibility=!logVisibility);});function setLogVisibility(bool){Array.from(output.getElementsByClassName('log')).forEach(ee=>{ee.style.display=bool ?'block':'none';e.innerText=bool ?'[log(on)]':'[log(off)]';});}setLogVisibility(logVisibility);});window.addEventListener('error',(evt)=>(addEntry(evt.error.stack)));function addEntry(string,category='error'){append(output,"<DIV class='entry "+category+"'/>",e=>{e.style.marginTop='0.5em';e.style.borderTop='1px solid #888';e.style.fontWeight=category=='error'?'bold':'';append(e,'<CODE/>',e=>{e.innerText=string;});});};const oldConsoleLog=console.log;console.log=function(...args){oldConsoleLog(...args);addEntry(args.join(' '),'log');};function testingIfErrorLogWorks_a(){testingIfErrorLogWorks_b();}function testingIfErrorLogWorks_b(){noSuchFunction();}setTimeout(testingIfErrorLogWorks_a,10);setTimeout(()=>console.log('LogTest'),20);setTimeout(testingIfErrorLogWorks_b,30);})();undefined;
```

I have added these as bookmarks on Google Chrome (Windows 10), and synchronized to iOS and Android.

On Android and Windows, both scripts work as expected:

- `DebugSimple.js` replaces the body of the page by a log of errors with backtrace, and `console.log` invocations.
- `DebugOverlay.js` ads an iframe overlay, where the errors are logged more cleanly.

On iOS, the simpler script `DebugSimple.js` will execute and log errors as expected, hence I know of that errors are being captured on iOS, albeit with less helpful output than on Android and Windows 10. This includes syntax errors, like typing `javascript:};` into the URL bar (syntax error).

However, if I invoke the `DebugOverlay.js` script, even if I manually copy-paste it from the bookmarks, nothing happens at all; `DebugSimple.js` doesn't report any kind of error either.

I suspect, that it may be related to the length of the bookmarklet, as this behavior seems to occur for large bookmarklets mostly; But regardless, it seems strange that there is nothing at all, that would indicate the cause.

At this point I don't know how to proceed; Keep in mind that I don't have any Mac device.

### Formatted source of `DebugSimple.js`

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
document.body.style.all = 'initial';

function putString(string) {
    document.body.innerText += string;
}


const oldConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(...args) {
    putString('(log) ' + args.map(e => e.toString()).join(' '));
    return oldConsoleLog(...args);
};

window.addEventListener('error', event => {
    var msg = '\n(err) ';
    msg += 
        !event ? '!!event = ' + event :
        !event.error ? '!!event.error = ' + event.error :
        !event.error.stack ? '!!event.error.stack = ' + event.error.stack :
        event.error.stack;
    if(event && event.error) for(const key in event.error) {
        msg += '\nevent.error.' + key + '=' + event.error[key];
    }
    putString(msg);
});

// Test error.

console.log("Log test.");
setTimeout(backtraceTest,10);
function backtraceTest(){ backtraceTest2(); }
function backtraceTest2(){ noSuchFunctionShouldExist(); }
```

### Formatted source of `DebugOverlay.js`

```
// DOES NOT WORK IN CHROME WHEN PASTED TO THE CONSOLE.
// The console messes somehow with error events.
// Should work when executed as bookmarklet or 'javascript:' URI.

const highestZIndex = Math.max(
    ...Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*'))
        .map(e=>window.getComputedStyle(e).zIndex)
        .map(parseInt)
        .filter(e => !isNaN(e)));
console.log(highestZIndex);

function append(parent, html, callback = undefined) {
    var e = document.createElement('DIV');
    parent.appendChild(e);
    e.outerHTML = html;
    e = parent.lastElementChild;
    if(callback) callback(e);
    return e;
}

const ifr = document.createElement('IFRAME');
document.body.prepend(ifr);
ifr.id = 'debugOverlay.js';
ifr.style.all = 'initial';
ifr.style.zIndex = highestZIndex + 1;
ifr.style.position = 'fixed';
ifr.style.left = '5%';
ifr.style.right = '5%';
ifr.style.width = '90%';
ifr.style.height = '90%';
ifr.style.opacity = '90%';
ifr.style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
ifr.style.border = '1pt solid #888';

// Firefox requires content to be initialized.
ifr.contentDocument;
ifr.contentDocument.open();
ifr.contentDocument.close();

const header = append(ifr.contentDocument.body, "<DIV id='header'/>", e => {
    e.style.position = 'static';
});
const closeButton = append(header, "<A href='#' id='closeButton'>[CLOSE]</A>", e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => ifr.parentElement.removeChild(ifr));
});
const clearButton = append(header, "<A href='#' id='clearButton'>[CLEAR]</A>", e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        output.innerHTML = '';
    });
});

const output = append(ifr.contentDocument.body, "<DIV id='outputPane'/>", e => {
    e.style.fontFamily = 'Sans';
});

append(ifr.contentDocument.body, "<DIV id='overScroll' style='height:30vh'/>");

var fontSizeScale = 0.8;
function setOutputFontSize(scale) {
    output.style.fontSize = (fontSizeScale * 100) + '%';
}
setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale);
const fontSizePlus = append(header, "<A href='#' id='fontSizePlus'>[LGR]</A>", e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale *= 1.2);
    });
});
const fontSizeMinus = append(header, "<A href='#' id='fontSizePlus'>[SML]</A>", e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setOutputFontSize(fontSizeScale /= 1.2);
    });
});

const toggleLog = append(header, "<A href='#' id='toggleLog'>[log(on)]</a>", e => {
    var logVisibility = true;
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setLogVisibility(logVisibility = !logVisibility);
    });
    function setLogVisibility(bool) {
        Array.from(output.getElementsByClassName('log')).forEach(ee => {
            ee.style.display = bool ? 'block' : 'none';
            e.innerText = bool ? '[log(on)]' : '[log(off)]';
        });
    }
    setLogVisibility(logVisibility);
});



window.addEventListener('error', (evt) => (addEntry(evt.error.stack)));

function addEntry(string, category='error') {
    append(output, "<DIV class='entry "+category+"'/>", e => {
        e.style.marginTop = '0.5em';
        e.style.borderTop = '1px solid #888';
        e.style.fontWeight = category == 'error' ? 'bold' : '';
        append(e, '<CODE/>', e => { e.innerText = string; });
    });
};

const oldConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function (...args) {
    oldConsoleLog(...args);
    addEntry(args.join(' '), 'log');
};


// For testing.
function testingIfErrorLogWorks_a() { testingIfErrorLogWorks_b(); }
function testingIfErrorLogWorks_b() { noSuchFunction(); }
setTimeout(testingIfErrorLogWorks_a,10);
setTimeout(()=>console.log('LogTest'), 20);
setTimeout(testingIfErrorLogWorks_b,30);
```

Comment: Bookmarklets aren't the place for large structured code. Consider using a userscript instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do, but not for functionality I need on mobile. I am not aware of any browser that supports user scripts on iOS; And even if one exists, the chance that it also has bookmark and tab synchronization with a delay of only a few seconds is slim. That part goes for Android too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you make userscript that does absolutely nothing until something in its UI is clicked? AFAIK userscripts are great for something that runs every single time, but on-demand actions (like those from Custom Buttons or deprecated GM_registerMenuCommand or, well, bookmarklets) are not reliably achievable nowadays. (IMBW)

Comment: @myf Userscripts are not possible on iOS, at least not without having a developer account and a Mac. As I understand, the AppStore conditions prohibit the execution of code, that didn't go through an Apple review.

Comment: @kdb I might consider you to use ideone.com to store some raw-code, and **appendChild** plain text as a javascript-code. See here for the code (part II.5.2): https://pikabu.ru/story/posobie_po_zapusku_javascript_konsol_bukmarkletyi_i_prochee_s_primerami_7676787 Than will let you not to be limited to the number of symbols.